# BroadcastReceiver not working via AndroidManifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have some `BroadcastReceiver` named `LocalTokenRequestReceiver` in my app.
I'm trying to send broadcast from another app.

This approach works fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* ..... */
        LocalTokenRequestReceiver localTokenRequestReceiver = new LocalTokenRequestReceiver();
        IntentFilter localTokenRequestFilter = new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.local_token_request));

        localTokenRequestFilter.addCategory(getString(R.string.broadcast_category));
        registerReceiver(localTokenRequestReceiver, localTokenRequestFilter);
    }
}
```

But it does not work this way:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".LocalTokenRequestReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="@string/local_token_request" />

        <category android:name="@string/broadcast_category" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Why is this may be so? I'm testing my app on Android 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

`<intent-filter>` does not support resources. Use explicit strings.

See [`<action>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html) and [`<category>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html).